# Remove js file for specific type of product view

Tags: layout, javascript, grouped-products

I need to remove/disable a js file which is loaded in page.xml, within the block `<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">`, but just for "Grouped" products.

The file name is jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js and I tried to disable it by adding:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js</name></action>
```

Inside: `<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">` in catalog.xml file.
This didn't worked. How can I achieve this?.
I've already tried to disable this js file by adding a script in view.phtml file, but didn't work neither.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following snippet of XML to the `local.xml` of the active template/package in your shop. This way you are sure the `removeItem` method is called after all `addItem` calls

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js</name></action>
   </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Comment: and as always, don't forget to clear your cache! :)