# difficulties with displaying succes message after form is sent

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I'm still learning the code languages that I used to create my form with. So I can't seem to figure out what seems to be the problem. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" class="field-divided" maxlength="15"  placeholder="Voornaam *" />&nbsp;<input type="text" id="mail-lastname" name="lastname" class="field-divided" maxlength="15" placeholder="Achternaam" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="email" id="mail-email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="field-long" maxlength="40" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type ="text" id="mail-phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" class="field-long" maxlength = "15">
        </li>
        <li>
            <select name="subject" id="mail-subject" class="field-select" >
            <option disabled value="" selected hidden >--Onderwerp-- *</option>
            <option value="Kennismakingsgesprek">Kennismakingsgesprek</option>
            <option value="Meer informatie">Meer informatie</option>
            <option value="activiteit">Aanmelding activiteit</option>
            <option value="Vraag/klacht">Vraag/klacht</option>
            <option value="Contact">Overig</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="information" id="mail-information"  placeholder =" Je bericht *"class="field-long field-textarea" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
        </li>
        <button class="mail-submit" id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Send e-mail</button>
        <span class="form-message"></span>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#mail-submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#mail-name").val();
    var lastname = $("#mail-lastname").val();
    var email = $("#mail-email").val();
    var phone = $("#mail-phone").val();
    var subject = $("#mail-subject").val();
    var information = $("#mail-information").val();
    $.post(
        "mail.php", 
        {
            name: name,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            subject: subject,
            information: information,
            submit: "yes" 
        },
        function(data){
            $(".form-message").html( data );
        }
    );
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $email_to = "#";

    $email_subject = "#";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $information = $_POST['information'];


    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;

    if (empty($name) || empty($lastname) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || empty($subject) || empty($information)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Voer alle velden in!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Geef een geldig E-mail!</span>";
        $errorEmail = true; 
    }
    else {
        $formcontent=" Naam: $name \n\n Achternaam: $lastname \n\n Email: $email \n\n Telefoon: $phone \n\n Onderwerp: $subject \n\n Informatie: $information";
        $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
        $headers = "From: ". htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) ." <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        mail($email_to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);
    }

}
else {
    echo "Not working!";
}

?>
```

What I'm looking for is that the page doesn't refresh after the form has been sent, so that it can display the form-succes or error message.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can do this using Jquery and Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works - though it is jQuery rather than JS.
Make sure the jQuery library is loaded on the page where you display the form.

I.e. as a quick test put

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

into your HTML.

In case there is actually a relation to Magento in your question you might be interested in this posts about how to integrate jQuery in Magento:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962366/how-can-i-use-jquery-on-magento-1-9-0-1-rwd-theme
- [Google CDN jQuery with Local Fallback in Magento Layout XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/google-cdn-jquery-with-local-fallback-in-magento-layout-xml/3625#3625)
- [Remove js file for specific type of product view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/remove-js-file-for-specific-type-of-product-view/12978#12978)